# Jquery calling same functions on ajaxComplete and ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have few functions like **foundation()** and **jScrollPane()** that I am calling on page load, but I also call them on **ajaxComplete**

Is there an easier way to do this except adding the same content bellow

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

and bellow

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
```

despite the fact that the current one is working fine ?

Comment: **document ready** cant work. This event will only called if the page fully loaded. After that, this event will not longer been fired.

Comment: Let me be a bit more specific. My web site is Ajax based but it has a static fallback for SEO. I call the functions on document ready for the static load, but when I load other pages or reload the current one with Ajax I have to call them again under the ajaxComplete. So that makes firing the same functions on 2 distances and my question is if there is a way to do that better ?

Comment: First, SEO is  believed to be a myth. Second, bots don't do JS (maybe except Google) thus `$(document).ready()` will not run for the bot. Have the contents in HTML instead.

Comment: I know bots ignore javascript. When you initially load the page it goes for the fallback content, the first load does not call the ajax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply move your initialization to the separate function, let say `initUI` and call if from both event handlers:

```
function initUI() {
    foundation(); 
    jScrollPane();
}

$(function() {
    initUI();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    initUI();
});
```

or even shorter

```
$(initUI);
$(document).ajaxComplete(initUI);
```

or the shortst version I can think of and my favorite:

```
$(document).on('ajaxComplete ready', initUI);
```

Comment: What about at calling dynamic content? If a Page has a slider which is called by `ready` at loading and also a select element which changes the slider content over ajax and the slider needs to be called by `ajaxComplete`? At loading the page both are loaded, if you run any javascript action than its also ajaxComplete?

Comment: If you bind both ready and ajaxComplete events, and make AJAX request on ready then initUI will be called twice: once for each event.

Comment: Can you give a sample Code?

Comment: I gave it in the answer. Or I don't understand what you mean. Explain your problem better maybe.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap and if I click a Dropdown Menu than it is running the ajaxcomplete which shouldnt. Here is running ajaxcomplete without a problem https://electronics.semaf.at/Create-Your-Kit (select Lattepanda). But here https://electronics.semaf.at/Batterie-Halter-4xAA-Jack-Connector if you click the Cart Button than it is calling ajaxComplete again and the Images are duplicated.